# Matlab- How to create network graph with various size

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

Hi I am interested in creating sensor nodes with various size. I have code to generate network graph. But it is not working for network size.

```
N=input('Enter the No. of Nodes');
G = graph(N)
```

If I use `G=graph` it displays graph where I need to plot nodes and edges manually.
But I want to create nodes and edges automatically with various size.

Comment: Have you ever tried plot(G) and its options? It has various options that you can play with.

Comment: I no need to plot the graph. If I give the input as node=100. It has to generate random undirected graph for me. From that I will create adjacency matrix

Comment: A = adjacency(G) it will display the node connectivity.The problem is to create random undirected with various input size.

Comment: I've used 'igraph' library of 'R' to generate random graphs.

Comment: I need it in matlab code.